# MVC model not saving the value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
        var ticketnumber = TempData["ticketId"] as Ticket;
        ticketnumber.TicketId = model.TicketId;
        db.SaveChanges();
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData"];
            UploadRepository service = new UploadRepository();
            int i = service.UploadImageInDataBase(file, model);
```

I have the value inside my tempdata but when i try to assign the value of it to the model value it doesnt save and even in debug it tells me the value hasnt changed so i just dont get what i am doing wrong.

Comment: a [mcve] would be great

Comment: Did you debug? What happens?

Comment: When i debug my temp data has the correct value i want but when i go to assign it to the model.TicketId it stays at 0 when the value of ticketnumber.TicketId is 2

Comment: Where does it stay 0? Give more details!

Comment: model.TicketId stays at 0 i am taking ticketnumber.TicketId which has a TicketId of 2 and when i assign it to model.TicketId my model.TicketId stays at 0

Comment: Well, as you see you are assinging model.TicketId to ticketnumber.TicketId, it should be the other way around.

Comment: Yup thanks for the help man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the assignment:

From:

```
ticketnumber.TicketId = model.TicketId;
```

To:

```
model.TicketId = ticketnumber.TicketId;
```

Comment: Lol holycrap thanks man wont make that rookie mistake again